# Remote glassfish deployment has been failed using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, glassfish, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to deploy the war to remote Glassfish 4.1 server using Jenkins (V2.138.1) deploy to container plugin(v1.13) with following configuration

```
WAR/EAR files : target/myapp.war
Context path  : /myapp
Containers    :
Glassfish 3.x
               credential : admin/****
               Glassfish home : 
               Glassfish admin port : 4848
               Glassfish hostname : my-pc
```

But following error occurred :

**ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: Deployment has failed: Action failed Deploying application to target server failed; java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException**

```
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.waitForProgressObject(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:295)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.deploy(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:133)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.redeploy(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:217)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1077)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1060)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1073)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1840)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52160923/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-glassfish-4-server-using-jenkins

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy a war file in GlassFish 4 server Using Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52160923/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-glassfish-4-server-using-jenkins)

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem with Glassfish v4.1.1
I upgraded Glassfish to v4.2.1. It's work for me:)